# Render book cover on box

Tags: javascript, animation, 3d, three.js, css-animations

I have some images of book covers. I need to render them to make them look like there are a 3d book.  Is there a way to do this using javascript or css?  Further are there ways using a physics engine to make it look like this book is falling?

Comment: Basically, yes to both questions. There are many ways to do this with css and javascript. You have to be more specific if you want a more specific answer. Have you done a google search, I'm sure there are tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

it's doable in both [js](http://threejs.org/) and [css](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/).

and as for the falling book / physics, try [physi.js](https://chandlerprall.github.io/Physijs/)